# SQLite - FOREIGN KEY doesn't work (yes, it is enabled)

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

For some reason, I cannot get FOREIGN KEY to work.

Any INSERT into primary_specs will go through, despite the 'ad_ids' table being empty.

EDIT: for some reason the INSERT will NOT go through when using DB Browser, but my python script waltzes right pass that constraint and is able to save the data...

---

Main table:

```
CREATE TABLE "ad_ids" (
    "ad_id" INTEGER,
    "ad_url"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("ad_id")
)
```

---

Secondary table:

```
CREATE TABLE "primary_specs" (
    "ad_id" INTEGER,
    "version"   TEXT,
    "year"  INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("ad_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("ad_id")
        REFERENCES ad_ids("ad_id")
)
```

---

```
PRAGMA foreign_key_list(primary_specs);
```

returns:

```
id    seq    table    from       to    on_update    on_delete    match
 0      0   ad_ids   ad_id    ad_id    NO ACTION    NO ACTION     NONE
```

---

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys
```

returns 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` is applied on connection and not a database.

Comment: Yup, has to be enabled every time you open a database, just like [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) says.